# Problem with sentence ぶった！この子ぶった！

Tags: words, colloquial-language, gemination

What does ぶった mean in this context? I can't find the word in any dictionary.

Comment: ぶった is the past-tense or completed-aspect conjugation of a verb.  Dictionaries generally don't include entries for conjugated forms.  Try looking up the plain form ぶる.

Comment: Can try looking up ぶつ as well

Comment: It's not the past form of ぶる but ぶつ([打]{ぶ}つ, ≂なぐる, たたく)...　https://jisho.org/word/%E6%89%93%E3%81%A4-1

Comment: もうちょっと詳しく説明してもらえますか？ぶるが成り立つ文脈も想像できるような気がします…

Comment: ^ 「ぶる」って？ 「[振]{ふ}る」・「[降]{ふ}る」？ 「XX[振]{ぶ}る」や「[振]{ふ}る」なら、「 **ぶ**った！この子ぶった！」ってならないし。。

Comment: 明鏡では「ぶる」になってますが、接尾の振るが由来ですね…

Comment: For some reason I didn't think it could be a verb. Brainfart. Someone was hit before that panel, so I guess butsu makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie 「ぶりっ子をする」というような意味で「ぶる」と言っている場面なら考えられなくもないですが、文脈に支えられた上でのかなりcreativeな使い方になると思います。辞書には「ぶる」の「気取った」という意味が載っていますが、これを現代人が話し言葉で使うことはもうないかと……

Comment: @broccoliforest, 言葉の使い分けについて説明してありがとうございます。^^